# ODE arising in physics

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I was solving a physics excercise that basically was about considering an object being gravitationally pulled from earth during a given time, but considering the variation of gravity along the way (it doesnt travel enough to  crash with the earth).
So, if the object started at distance $d$ from the center of the earth and $f(t)$ is the distance that the object travels in $t$ seconds, then

$$f''(t)=\frac{-k}{(d-f(t))^2}$$
Since both sides are the acceleration of the object at time $t$ ($k$ is a constant). Substituting $f(t)=d-\sqrt[3]{k}h(t)$:

$$h''(t)h^2(t)=1$$
How would I go about solving this differential equation? I am new to this branch of calculus. Thanks in advance.

**Edit:** Robert Israel's observation about the sign of $f''(t)$

Comment: [See Wolfram Alpha's solution.](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+y%27%27%28t%29+%3D+a%2Fy%28t%29%5E2) It's not absolutely horrible but not great either.

Comment: @CameronWilliams WA's answer should be correct, but it is not enlightening at all. I would appreciate learning about the process of how to solve it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $h$ represents distance from the centre of the earth and you want gravitation to be attractive, it should be

$$h'' = - k/h^2$$

Conservation of energy: $\dfrac{(h')^2}{2} - \dfrac{k}{h} $ is constant.
If you have less than escape velocity, this constant is negative, so let's write it as $-E$.

Thus $$h' = \pm\sqrt{2k/h - E}$$  This is a separable DE,
so we integrate:

$$ t = \pm \int \sqrt{\dfrac{h}{2(k - E h)}}\; dh + c$$

Substitute $u = 2(k - E h)$:

$$\eqalign{\int \sqrt{\dfrac{h}{2(Eh-k)}}\; dh &= \dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{4 E^{3/2}} \int \sqrt{2k/u - 1}\; du\cr
&= \dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{4 E^{3/2}}\left(\sqrt{2ku - u^2} - k \arctan\left(\dfrac{k-u}{\sqrt{2ku-u^2}}\right)\right)+c\cr
&= \dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{4 E^{3/2}}\left(2 \sqrt{Eh(k-Eh)} + k \arctan \left( \dfrac{k/2 - Eh}{\sqrt{Eh(k-Eh)}}\right)\right)+c} $$